# What tool can I use to calculate achieved statistical power for multiple mediation with 5 mediators?

Tags: statistics, spss, process-macro

I ran a multiple mediation analysis with 5 parallel mediators, using Process Macro in SPSS 29. So far, I have not found a tool to calculate post-hoc power. What kind of online tools there are that could calculate it?
I have looked into https://schoemanna.shinyapps.io/mc_power_med/ but this supports only up to 3 mediators. G*power is not a suitable option for the analysis and I do not know R nor SAS.
Thanks for any suggestions!